# how to add recycler view on dialog

Tags: android

Im trying to add recycler view on dialog but dialog not showing anything...I have added cards on recycler view and want to display recycler view on dialog

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_transaction_report, null);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.transactio_rep_recyclerView);
dialog.setView(dialogView);

AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
// alertDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
alertDialog.show();

adapter = new TransactionReportCardAdapter(listTransactionDetails, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `R.layout.dialog_layout` is a layout with recyclerview

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();

RecyclerView rvTest = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rvTest);
rvTest.setHasFixedSize(true);
rvTest.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
rvTest.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(context, R.drawable.divider));

DataDialogAdapter rvAdapter = new DataDialogAdapter(context, rvTestList);
rvTest.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down_dialog</item>
</style>
```

Comment: setAdapter() in recyclerView cannot applied to LastTransactionsAdapter class

Comment: @suraj What is LastTransactionsAdapter class?

Comment: set data on textview and these textview  were added on cardview

Answer (score 4):

You can create one layout that contains `RecyclerView` then set it in dialog :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(your recycler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            val rcvDialog = RecyclerView(this@MainActivity)

            rcvDialog.adapter = DialogAdapter(ArrayList<Item>) //DialogAdapter create by your self
            rcvDialog.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            dialogBuilder.setView(rcvDialog)

            val dialog: Dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
            dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TransactionReportCardAdapter  adapter = new TransactionReportCardAdapter(listTransactionDetails, context);
adapter.setAdapter(themeAdapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

you should use `LayoutManager` as it's responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a `RecyclerView`.